# What's the difference between MainActivity and BaseActivity?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently learning android app dev and I want to know what's the purpose of a BaseActivity as opposed to a MainActivity. I've looked through several source code and have seen people use BaseActivity without the MainActivity, while others have used MainActivity that extends BaseActivity. From what I've read, BaseActivity is used to define common elements you want through all activities.

In any case, would there be any difference between use just a BaseActivity rather than MainActivity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You answered your own question. Defining a `BaseActivity` is just a programming convention that people use to define common functionality. The benefit of making it a class is so that several other `Activity`s can inherit its common functionality. Android Activities are no different than any other Java class and following the basic rules of object oriented programming like inheritance and polymorphism. Let's say you had `FriendsListActivity` and `FollowersListActivity`. Well, both of those Activities probably make a network request and load a list view of some sort. You might want to define a `PersonListBaseActivity` and put functions like `fetchPeople(String url)` or `initializePersonAdapter(List<Person> people)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and for the reference to polymorphism. I have a clearer idea now.

Comment: @trungnt glad it helped!